# Listing class APIs with parameters and return types

Tags: java, api, reflection

I want to list all the APIs of the given jar ( for which I don't have javadoc) in following fashion any help on that?

```
PackageName, ClassName, API Name, ParamName:type;ParameterName:type,ReturnType
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem. Probably a number of tools to do something similar, though not exactly what you want. Certainly there would be an easy implementation with ASM. As it is, I whipped up one using reflection:

```
public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        java.util.jar.JarFile jar = new java.util.jar.JarFile(args[0]);
        java.util.Enumeration<java.util.jar.JarEntry> jarEntries = jar.entries();
        while (jarEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
            java.util.jar.JarEntry jarEntry = jarEntries.nextElement();
            String jarEntryName = jarEntry.getName();
            if (!jarEntryName.endsWith(".class")) {
                continue;
            }
            int jarEntryNameSuffixIndex = jarEntryName.length() - 6;
            String binaryName = jarEntryName.substring(0, jarEntryNameSuffixIndex).replaceAll("/", "\\.");
            Class<?> type = null;
            while (type == null) {
                try {
                    type = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(binaryName);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    int binaryNameQualifiedIndex = binaryName.indexOf(".");
                    if (binaryNameQualifiedIndex == -1) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("couldn't load class for " + jarEntryName);
                    } else {
                        binaryName = binaryName.substring(binaryNameQualifiedIndex + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            int typeModifiers = type.getModifiers();
            if (!(java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isPublic(typeModifiers) || java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isProtected(typeModi$
                continue;
            }
            String packageName = (type.getPackage() == null) ? "" : type.getPackage().getName();
            String typeName = type.getCanonicalName();
            for (java.lang.reflect.Method method : type.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                if (method.isSynthetic() || method.isBridge()) {
                    continue;
                }
                int methodModifiers = method.getModifiers();
                if (!(java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isPublic(methodModifiers) || java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isProtected(me$
                    continue;
                }
                String methodName = method.getName();
                System.out.print(packageName + ", " + typeName + ", " + methodName + ", ");
                for (Class<?> parameterType : method.getParameterTypes()) {
                    String parameterTypeName = parameterType.getCanonicalName();
                    System.out.print(":" + parameterTypeName + ", ");
                }
                Class<?> returnType = method.getReturnType();
                String returnTypeName = returnType.getCanonicalName();
                System.out.println(returnTypeName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Include the JAR (and its dependencies) in the classpath. This won't print the names of the parameters, since you can't get those via reflection. It also doesn't show type parameters or var-args, though you could get those.

Comment: Very nice solution, although I'd prefer it if the functionality was split up into several different methods. But you are doing everything the way I would have done it myself (+1)

Comment: @Sean: Yeah, just a bit of a brain dump. Definitely could use some refactoring.

Comment: Thanks Nathan its very helpful. Is there any way around to get the parameter names along with types?

Comment: The name of the parameters are stored by the bytecode, I think, but reflection does not give you a way to get at those. You can parse the bytecode yourself, or better yet use a library like ASM.

Comment: @nathan the argument names are only stored in the byte code if the code was compiled with the javac debug flag turned on. And yes, asm allows you to access parameter names

Comment: @Sean: Right, I think `javac` does not include parameter names as part of the default debugging information. Turn on with `-g` or `-g:vars`

Comment: Well instead of ASM we can use [paraNamer](http://paranamer.codehaus.org/) which is easier..

Answer (score 0):

You can try classdoc, which attempts to generate a javadoc from compiled files and jar archives.

http://classdoc.sourceforge.net/classdoc10/classdoc.html